# Should a semicolon cause an error in a <%=foo + " - " + bar%> line?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<% =reg.Event.Title + " - " + reg.Event.Date %>
```

Works.

```
<% =reg.Event.Title + " - " + reg.Event.Date; %>
```

Tosses a runtime error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

There are no mismatched operators - no unclosed '(' ...could something in a controller or further upstream in the backend be to blame?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably ´<%= ... %>´ is turned into a Response.Write() statement during compilation, e.g:

```
Response.Write(reg.Event.Title + " - " + reg.Event.Date;);
```

...then the semicolon is definitely incorrect.

Comment: That's exactly the case. <%=X%>is merely a convenient short handhand for Response.Write(X).  Therefore whatever X is, it must be syntactically suitable.

Answer (score 2):

When using <%= %> leave off the semi colon. If you used <% Response.Write(...) %> you could include the semi-colon. <%= %> is a shorthand notation for writing strings to the client.